# Find nearest N points to a give point in N-dimentional space

Tags: algorithm, search, machine-learning, r-tree

I got an N-dimentional space with millions of points. I am looking for the most efficient way to build a model which would allow to find K (K<100) points closest to a give point at run time.

List FindClosestMatch(Point target, Model model)

I start looking on R*-trees but wonder if this is the right approach...

Comment: Why not?  I'd say you give it a try.

Comment: milions does not seem too scary. What about precomputing everything? Then you have constant time lookup, and 100 * 10^6 still seems managable (especially when stored on HDD)

Comment: Yes, R-trees support this, or k-d-trees or pretty much any other spatial/metrical index. That is their use case, finding nearby object fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R-Tree variants are a pretty good choice, but M-trees are a little better for your application, since you only need to compute one distance to determine how close a bounding sphere is to your target point:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-tree

Comment: Actually M-trees do not work very well in use, because of their much more expensive construction.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. The construction time is not an issue but I want to optimize lookup time. I will look into M-Trees

Answer (score 0):

You can partition your space into n-cubes such that the expected number of points in a cube is rk for some value of r > 1 to be determined. Then for a given query p:

```
1. Consider the 3^n n-cubes at most 1 away from the cube p is in.
2. Calculate the shortest distance d between p and one of these cubes.
3. Find the distance between p and each point in these cubes.
4. If the total number of points within d is >= k, return the k closest.
5. If not, expand your radius by one cube and repeat.
```

When you choose r, you're trading off having a larger default set of points to search through, vs likely having to expand the radius 1 or more times.

Comment: In an N dimensional space, that is 3^N cubes, not 9. Consider a 10 dimensional space, then you have over 50000 neighbor cubes.

Comment: Thank you, Dave and Anony-Mousse. The number of dimensions is large enough... N=~500, 3^500 wouldn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You nay also want to look at [Cover Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cover_tree), which are especially for kNN-searches. I also found that the [PH-Tree](http://www.phtree.org) (my own) performs almost as well as the Cover Tree for 15 or 25 dimensions, while being much more space efficient in memory, especially for large datasets, and allowing fast inserts/updates.

A comparative Java implementation of many algorithms is available in the [ELKI Framework](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/).